# How to disable/Hide ui-grid column menu-items dynamically at runtime

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

[image: Ui-grid with menu-items]

How can I disable/Hide menu-items of the column conditionally?

Comment: Is there any in-built property to hide perticular menu-item in column?

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name', enableColumnMenu: false },
      { field: 'gender', enableHiding: false, suppressRemoveSort: true, sort: { direction: uiGridConstants.ASC } },
      {
        field: 'company',
        menuItems: [
          {
            title: 'Outer Scope Alert',
            icon: 'ui-grid-icon-info-circled',
            action: function($event) {
              this.context.blargh(); // $scope.blargh() would work too, this is just an example
            },
            context: $scope
          },
          {
            title: 'Grid ID',
            action: function() {
              alert('Grid ID: ' + this.grid.id);
            }
          },
          {
            title: 'Column Title Alert',
            shown: function () {
              return this.context.col.displayName === 'Company';
            },
            action: function() {
              alert(this.context.col.displayName);
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
```

You can customize a column's menu and provide your own functionality.  Each menu item can have:

- `shown`: a function that determines whether or not to display the item
- `title`: the title you'd like to have displayed for the menu item (note that you can also
  use i18n on this through the `gridMenuTitleFilter` setting)
- `icon`: an icon you'd like displayed alongside the item
- `action`: a function that will be called when the menu is clicked
- `active`: a function that highlights the item (giving a toggle type effect - see the sort on the column menus for an example)
- `context`: by default, the `action`, `shown` and `active`'s' contexts will have a reference to the grid added as the
  property `grid` (accessible through `this.grid`.  You can pass in your own context by supplying
  the `context` property to your menu item. It will be accessible through `this.context`.